# How to Fetch a place using place id (latest)?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Can anyone show me some example of fetching a place using place id? and get the places information? i can't follow the tutorial by google

i can't follow the tutorial by google in this link..
[here's the link about the latest google place](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you follow [Google's migration guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)? If you haven't migrated yet please do so as soon as possible since the old Places SDK for Android is deprecated.

As for how to fetch place details by place ID, you can use the fetchPlace() method.

Take a look at [Google's code example](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details#get-place) below:

```
// Define a Place ID.
String placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE";

// Specify the fields to return.
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

// Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
    Place place = response.getPlace();
    Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getName());
}).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
        // Handle error with given status code.
        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you get started!

Answer (score 0):

It's how you set up your placesClient variable. Use `let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient.shared()` instead of `var placesClient = GMSPlacesClient`